# Adding <input> to Leaflet 1.0.0 layers control throws an error

Tags: javascript, leaflet

My intention is to add transparency sliders to each layer in a `L.control.layers`. I was going to use a simple HTML5 slider `<input>`, demonstrated here:

http://geohackers.in/2013/10/leafelt-layer-opacity-control-using-html5-slider/

However, when I add an `<input>` to the legend string in a `L.control.layers`, I get an error:

```
leaflet.js:12457 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'layer' of undefined(…)
_checkDisabledLayers @ leaflet.js:12457
_addItem @ leaflet.js:12411
_update @ leaflet.js:12325
onAdd @ leaflet.js:12174
addTo @ leaflet.js:11610
(anonymous function) @ index.html:144
```

Removing the `<input>` fixes the error. What's the explanation?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle/jsbin/playground for this?

Comment: OK, I made one: https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/wipo/edit?html,output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your question is, literally:

> What's the explanation?

I'm going to give you an explanation, and not a solution :-)

The Leaflet code for `L.Control.Layers` iterates through the radio buttons / checkboxes frequently, to check which buttons/boxes to mark as enabled.

In order to do so, it uses this one line of code (in the `_onInputClick` and `_checkDisabledLayers` private methods):

```
    var inputs = this._form.getElementsByTagName('input'),
```

This iterates through all the checkboxes and radio buttons inside the control. The downside is that, due to the way the code is written right now, it also iterates through *any other `<input>` elements inside the control*.

In other words: `L.Control.Layers` *expects* that all the `<input>`s inside it are either a checkbox or a radio button that enables/disables a leaflet layer. That's why Leaflet expects every `<input>` element to have a `layerId` property here:

```
        layer = this._getLayer(input.layerId).layer;
```

See `input.layerId`? That's what's triggering your error.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. So without Leaflet checking explicitly for `layerId` as part of its identification of the layer checkboxes/radio buttons, it's not possible to put an `<input>` in a layers control? I'll try adding a `layerId` property to my slider purely out of curiosity (and mischief), but one imagines that will fundamentally break everthing.

Comment: See https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/5116 :-D

Comment: Hi. I'm trying to work on a similar task which requires adding additional input checkbox in the layers control. Apparently this issue has been resolved but I'm still getting the same error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'layer' of undefined(…)
_checkDisabledLayers @ leaflet.js:12457

Do I need to add some additional attributes to the input for leaflet to ignore it?